# How to evaluate multiple limits in a matrix array MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

this is my question:

Suppose the next 2 arrays:

Z = [1 2;3 6;2 4];
Y = [1 2 3 5 2 3 5 7 1 0 4 6]

Now I want to get something like this:

X = {[1 2];[3 5 2 3];[2 3 5]}

As you can see, variable "X" has the corresponding values of vector "Y", which positions are contained by variable Z. I was thinking in something like this:

fun = @(c) Y(c(1,1):c(1,2));
X = arrayfun(fun,Z)

But it doesn't work :(, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
X = arrayfun(@(n) Y(Z(n,1):Z(n,2)), 1:size(Z,1), 'uni', 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

`bsxfun` approach -

```
t1 = bsxfun(@times,1:numel(Y),ones(size(Z,1),1))
t2 = bsxfun(@ge,t1,Z(:,1)) & bsxfun(@le,t1,Z(:,2))
t3 = bsxfun(@times,t2,Y)
X = cellfun(@nonzeros,mat2cell(t3,ones(1,size(Z,1)),numel(Y)),'uni',0)
```

Comment: @LuisMendo It's like oxygen for me! :)